# How to force install an rpm?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, gitlab, gitlab-auto-devops

I have a gitlab pipeline where I will be installing latest rpm everytime.

Some times, even if the target machine is changed manually, the rpm should be installed successfully.

But some how I am getting below error.

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Ignored option -q, -v, -d or -e (probably due to merging: -yq != -y -q)
605133599.rpm                                                                                    | 124 kB  00:00:00
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-RG0U7M/605133599.rpm: myproject-nightlye2e-1.x86_64
/var/tmp/yum-root-RG0U7M/605133599.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
```

So even if the machine is having not installed any version or older/latest/same version installed, when I ran below yum install with an rpm file, it should force install or update.

```
yum install -yq rpmfilepath
```

How to do that?

Please suggest.

Comment: First of all: Did you read and understand the error message? `Ignored option -q, -v, -d or -e (probably due to merging: -yq != -y -q)`

Comment: Second: Did you read and understand the second message? `does not update installed package`

Answer (score 0):

If you satisfy all the package prerequisites you can run command like:

```
rpm -U package.rpm
```

to force install the package even if it is installed.

Comment: a) He is using `yum`. b) "Satisfying prerequisites" and after that running `rpm` doesn't make sense. For this we have yum/dnf. c) Your answer does not address his issues or explain what he is doing wrong.

Comment: @reichhart, do you know `yum` is based on `rpm`? It make, I talk about required prerequisites. I give solution, for the rest there are manuals.

Comment: Why do you think that I wrote that using `rpm` after "satisfying prerequisites" doesn't make sense? I understood "prerequisites" as dependant packages. A single RPM command is not a generic solution because if in future new package versions will require additional dependant packages which are not installed then your command will fail. Hence better use yum. BTW - I create RPM packages since mid 90s and run different public yum repos for more than 15 years.

Comment: BTW - `-F` does not force. It does "freshen" and hence won't install the package if there is no older version.

Comment: @reichhart, correct. Will update my answer

Answer (score -1):

Do not merge options when using `yum`. Simply use this command:

```
yum install -y rpmfilepath >/dev/null
```

The reason why I am using `>/dev/null` amd not `-q` here is that it won't suppress messages about installed dependencies. Example:

```
# yum install -y -q rpmfilepath 

Installed:
  glibc-2.31-6.fc32.i686   libgcc-10.3.1-1.fc32.i686   rpmfilepath
```

If it is really required (e.g. in case of downgrades) then you can afterwards simply run

```
# rpm -U --force rpmfilepath
```

`yum` would have installed the dependencies and after that you can `--force` (=`--replacepkgs --replacefiles --oldpackage`) the installation with `rpm`.

Comment: the first message is just warning to use -y instead of -yq. But the installation is not getting updated, I need to force update exiting installation

Comment: any command to update the package even if new/old/same version installed.

Comment: There is no force in yum like it is in rpm. The question is: Why would you want to "force" the installation of a package which is already installed? What do you want to achieve?